# dev-c++ socket errors

Tags: c, sockets, mingw, dev-c++

I've tryed to compile client-server example using TCP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) in DevC++, but I get error messages: 
[Linker error] undefined reference to 'socket'
[Linker error] undefined reference to 'htons'
etc
I have installed MingW

Answer (score 2):

You need to link to `ws2_32.lib` - Typically using `-lws2_32` on the linker commandline

Comment: What's the linker commandline?

Comment: -lws2_32 command line doesn't change anything in this case

Comment: A missing include doesn't give a linker error - The error in your question is resolved by linking to the correct import library, if you have another error update your Q.

Comment: I've put lws2_32 as linker command but nothing gets solved.. Maybe I need to put some include directories or another linker command?

Comment: Please update your question with **code**, **compiler command**, **linker command** and **all errors**

Comment: Code is already mentioned in question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets

Comment: there are no compiler or linker commands as I'm, as I already said in question, using DevC++

Comment: I have already mentioned errors in comments here.

Comment: There **are** compiler and linker commands. DevC++ runs them for you. Show the complete output from a full rebuild.

Comment: I'm trying to compile it using codeblocks